# How to color ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse labels with fill color

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

Is it currently possible to make the *labels* generated with `ggforce::geom_mark_ellipse(label=)` colored?

In the example below, I'd like to see *versicolor* typeface in green:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but not in a straightforward way like you would with any other mapped aesthetics. You would have to build a new layer where you change the colour and filter the layers correctly. You can see this becoming quite laborious if you have 10+ groups each needing their own label colour.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)

ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Length, Petal.Width)) +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = Species, label = Species,
                        filter = Species != 'versicolor')) +
  geom_mark_ellipse(aes(fill = Species, label = Species,
                        filter = Species == 'versicolor'),
                    label.colour = "green") +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: I guess if you really want to have a label color that matches the color of the ellipse, you need to loop through "Species" and add the layer each time.. Quite a pain

Comment: If you want to be efficient about it, yes. The `"green"` colour is not the same as the ellipse's green, so it would probably be best to pre-define the colour palette for the labels as well.